# How can I resolve error - hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do

Tags: git, github

I am on master branch. I worked something locally and in mean time my coworker pushed some code on master.

I maked I mistake, I did not pulled from master  `git pull origin master` I just tried to add my new changes

```
git add . 
git commit -m "my commit"
git push origin master
```

now I get error

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

the momen when I insrted `git commit -m "my commit"` I "lost" my lcoal changes. By lost I mean the files where I maked changes, the code that I inserted etc...

I maked commit but I am not able to to git push.

How can I solve this problem where I will make git push with my changes ( without losing them )
and also to make git pull ?

Comment: "I "lost" my lcoal changes." No, you didn't. There is no problem here. Don't worry, be happy. And learn what Git is so that you understand what Git means when it talks to you. Just do what the message says to do! Say `git pull origin master`, then say `git push origin master`.

Comment: I lost because when i write git status I am not able to see the changed files anymore

Comment: Yup. But that just shows that you don't know what `git status` is about. Read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ and learn all kinds of stuff, including that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to get back your status as before, a `git reset @~` would be enough.

But the point of "add+commit" is to save your work into a new local commit, that you can examine with `git show`.

To push, you will need first to fetch and merge the remote changes first.

That is why I prefer setting a `stash` + `pull --rebase` by default ([Git 2.6+][1])

```bash
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, a simple `git pull` will replay (rebase) my local commits (the one not yet pushed like the one you just did) on top of the refreshed `origin/myCurrentBranch`, making sure my local work is not overridden.

If I have "unsubmitted" work (local modification not yet added to the index and committed), the "autostash" part make sure the work in progress is saved before the pull, and re-applied after the pull.

From there, a simple `git push` will work.